# onTap event of InkResponse not working for grid item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to execute a simple click event on the grid item in my list.  Below is my code which was build using many answers present on stack overflow but none of them is working for me. I wanted a ripple effect on click hence I have used InkResponse.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      childAspectRatio: 1.5,
      mainAxisSpacing: 30,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: gridItem(parentCalcList),
    )
    );
  }


List<Widget> gridItem(List<ParentCalculators> mParentCalcList) {
    List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < mParentCalcList.length; i++) {
      tiles.add(GridTile(
          child: InkResponse(
            child: getGridColumn(mParentCalcList.elementAt(i)),
            onTap: _gridItemClicked(i),
            enableFeedback: true,
      )));
    }
    return tiles;
  }

getGridColumn(ParentCalculators calc) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 1,
                child: Image.asset(
                  calc.icon,
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
              radius: 28,
            )),
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
            calc.name,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 14,
                height: 1.1,
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                wordSpacing: 0.5,
                letterSpacing: 0.8),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: What if you use `InkWell`, which is used in here [Flutter Ripples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples)

Comment: Use InkWell that'll work.

Comment: @Alok I tried using that but it gave a grid item blue color but tap event was not working.